edge браузер вкладки
такой вопрос браузер edge открывает каждую ссылку в новой вкладке
как отключить ?
а то на озоне лазишь а каждый товар в новой вкладке

Я рылся долго, ничего внятного не нашёл. В качестве идеи - на разных сайтах оно работает по-разному. Иногда переход происходит на новую страницу в текущей, иногда в новой вкладке, иногда в новом окне. Если я ничего не путаю, это так программируется. МС же предоставляет контекстное меню, в котором можно выбрать нужный вариант загрузки страницы по ссылке. Буду присматривать за темой, самому интересно.

спасибо _ ))) )
